# ASIHTTPRequest shouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground does not work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, asihttprequest

I'm trying to send a post form to a website via ASIHTTPRequest. When setting up the request, I set the property: [request shouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground]; and add the request to a ASINetworkQueue.  After [queue go] the "upload" begins. When I press the home button the requests seems to be paused and continues only after the app moved to foreground. Do I need to set up anything in a plist in order to allow network traffic when an app is in background?

Regards,
Dominik

Answer (score 0):

Can you post some of your code. It is hard to debug whats going on.

In addition to that the ASIHTTP framework comes with an example that demonstrates performing uploads in the background.

I ran the iPhone project on my simulator running iOS 5.x , and it works just fine.

You may want to try running the example to see if it works or not.

Hope it helps

Comment: Well, according to the documentation every request that is added to a queue is asynchronous. But nevertheless I could not find out how to check if the request is asynchronous :/

Comment: Thanks for your help. In the meanwhile I figured it out. The problem was I called [request shouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground] instead of "request.shouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground = YES;" That was the problem :) thank you